# Освобождение памяти массива связных списков

Tags: c

Создаю массив связных списков, но при освобождении памяти получаю segmentation fault. Функция где создаю массив списков, передаю указатель на массив и размер под выделение :

```
void    list_malloc(t_sector **list, int size)
{
    if (!(*list = (t_sector *)malloc(sizeof(t_sector) * size)))
        ft_error("Bad realloc");
}
```

сама структура :

```
typedef struct  s_sector
{
                int x0;
                int y0;
                struct s_sector *next;
}               t_sector;
```

Запись списков и робота с ними происходит хорошо! 
пример когда освобождаю память :

```
void    free_list(t_data *data, t_sector *list)
{
    t_sector *tmp;
    int i = -1;
    while (++i < data->for_realloc - 1)
    {
        while (list[i].next != NULL)
        {
            tmp = list[i].next;
            free(&list[i]);
            list[i] = *tmp;
        }
        i++;
    }
    free(list);
}
```

Уже день сижу не могу понять как правильно реализовать освобождения памяти для массива списков.

Comment: `free(&list[i]);` - по-моему, амперсенд там лишний.

Comment: @freim разобрался, правильный вид функции 

void free_list(t_data *data, t_sector **list)
{
 t_sector *tmp;
 int i = -1;
 while (++i < data->for_realloc - 1)
 {
  while (list[i]->next != NULL)
  {
   tmp = list[i]->next;
   free(list[i]);
   list[i] = tmp;
  }
 }
 free(list[i]);
}

и добавил ещё указатель в аргумент

Comment: @Vadim: И что же это такое? Функция выделения памяти у вас выделяет массив из `t_sector`. Здесь же у вас вдруг освобождается массив из `t_sector *`. Откуда вдруг взялся массив из `t_sector *` и какое он вообще имеет отношение к вопросу? И почему тогда условие в цикле `while (list[i]->next != NULL)`, а не `while (list[i] != NULL)`? Последний элемент списка вдруг освобождать не надо?

Answer (score 0):

У вас `list[i]` - это объект типа `t_sector`, это "заголовок" списка, который является элементом массива, выделенном вашим `malloc`. Ни каком `free(&list[i])` не может быть и речи. Эти объекты освобождаются у вас вместе со всем массивом вызовом `free(list)` в конце функции. Зачем вы еще пытаетесь делать какое-то `free(&list[i])` здесь и чего вы этим пытались добиться - совершенно не ясно.

Элементы списка, который вам нужно освободить, начинаются с `list[i].next`. Вот как может выглядеть ваш цикл освобождения

```
while (list[i].next != NULL)
{
  s_sector *tmp = list[i].next;
  list[i].next = list[i].next->next;
  free(tmp);
}
```

Все.

P.S. Что там у вас происходит с этими `++i` в таких количествах - тоже не ясно. Но это уже сами разбирайтесь. Что такое `t_data` и `data->for_realloc` нам отсюда не видно.